# Bios Boot Selection Menu?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, bios, multi-boot

I have two HDDs, one with Windows 8 installed on it, and one with Ubuntu 12.10 installed on it.

Seeing as Ubuntu is not installed alongside Windows, I can only assume that Windows doesn't even see Ubuntu.

My problem is that, I want to be able to select a device to boot from a bios menu. I know that Windows Boot Manager will not work and my bios keeps giving me the only option of selecting a "Boot First Device", which sequentially changes the boot priority via the bios permanently unless I change it back.

Ultimately I want to be able to have a choice when I turn on my computer, but am not given that option. My motherboard specs are as follows:

> Motherboard: Gigabyte Z68XP-UD3 (Intel Socket 1155)
>
> Bios: Award Software International, Inc. (Version 8)

Any ideas? Without having to change wires every time I wanted to load a different operating system? Or how to have a selection every time my computer is turned on, without changing the boot sequence?

Thank you so much!
Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the easiest way to do this is to install Linux after Windows; then the boot manager is automatically installed & configured.  Ubuntu comes with GRUB (or GRUB2) to manage the boot process.  Conversely, Windows is not able to offer the linux boot option without using 3rd party tools.

Since what you describe seems to indicate that you installed Windows after Ubuntu, you have to backtrack a bit.  You should be able to re-install GRUB and it should automatically detect the Windows installation and offer the options at boot.

There are good articles here:
http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:All#Dual-Booting_Windows_and_Ubuntu
and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

FWIW, nowadays, if you have a Windows installation and then install linux, almost all distros do this configuration for you painlessly and automatically.

Comment: Thank you for this Debra, but I actually installed Windows first on my primary HDD, and then installed Ubuntu on my secondary HDD and the Windows Boot Manager still doesn't load. If it was working correctly would Windows be automatically able to recognize another operating system on another Hard Drive? If so, the Windows Boot Manager isn't working properly?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that Windows can't manage this -- you have to either use 3rd party software, or else let Ubuntu's installation of GRUB manage it.  GRUB knows how to set up the Windows boot option, but Windows doesn't know how to set up a linux boot option.  Another (linux-associated) program that can manage this is called LILO, but GRUB is more commonly used nowadays.  Is it possible that you had the Windows drive disconnected when you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I was nervous that I would make a terrible mistake an accidentally select my Windows drive to install Ubuntu on, so I disconnected the Windows HDD.

Comment: You should rename the partitions. When selecting the mount points during install it will display the name, no need to worry. But it's better to know and remember your HDD's partition postion on disk. Currently if you don't want to reinstall ubuntu then the only way is that you manually add an entry of windows to Grub's `menu.lst` file